# Undefined offset: 1 (array filter)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have this arrangement that executes a foreach with the values ​​that a table sends, the problem arises that it is not filtering the empty values ​​and the array and it saves an empty value, that is, if I choose 1 and 4 in my table, it only stores the value of 1 and the second comes out empty.

this is my controller:

```
 $checked_array = $_POST['id_version'];

    foreach ($_POST['id_version'] as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($_POST['id_version'][$key], $checked_array))
        {
         
                    $soft_instal = new Software_instalacion;
                    $soft_instal->id_instalacion             = $instalaciones->id;
                    $soft_instal->id_historial               = $historial->id;
                    $soft_instal->id_usuario                 = $request->id_usuario;
                    $soft_instal->id_version                 = $_POST['id_version'][$key];
                    $soft_instal->obs_software               = $_POST['obs_software'][$key];
                    $soft_instal->id_tipo_venta              = $_POST['id_tipo_venta'][$key];
                    $soft_instal->save();

        }
            
    }
```

this is my view:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASmMy.png)

I would like to know how I can filter those empty values ​​of obs_software and id_tip_venta, that is, how can I apply the filter array

Comment: You have this tagged Laravel, so why are you using `$_POST['id_version']` instead of `$request->input('id_version')`? Additionally, when using Checkboxes, remember that if you don't check it, nothing is sent to the backend. With that being said, which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: The problem arises because if my user marks the first check and the last row, both the sales_type and the observation have a name like this: name="obs_software[]" so that this name is not filtering the empty rows and sends the controller ie in my table i have 4 rows if i select the 1 and 4

the name sends obs_software['1','','','4'] and what I'm looking for is that those voids can be filtered